About false hyphenation and \raggedright — TeX
In this example, TeX obviously knows that the first (1st) \hbox is overfull but does not hyphenate; in the second (2nd) \hbox, it does because of the \raggedright command.
I know how to handle it; the question is why TeX acts that way.
\parindent=0pt
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=40pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=41.52788pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\raggedright

\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=40pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=41.52788pt E\-le\-fan\-ten } 
\bye


See also \sloppy and \fussy.

The problem with the first box is that even though TeX cannot fit the text in the line, it also is not able to fill the line without some glue to fill out the line, so the algorithm decides to just let the line be overfull.
Thus, if you change the text from E\-le\-fan\-ten to die E\-le\-fan\-ten you will see that TeX is willing to hyphenate (although there’s still not enough default stretch in the inter-word space so you’ll still see an overfull box.

(To address a now-deleted comment on the original question: The non-hyphenation of the first word of a paragraph doesn’t come into play here because of the explicit discretionary hyphens.)

None of the breakpoints that you added are feasible as they do not hit the exact width, and there is no stretchable glue to adjust the line so that the breakpoint is at the righthand margin.
Using \raggedright provides stretchable glue at the right margin so this makes all breakpoints feasible.
In most cases there is interword space which can stretch (and can be made to stretch more if needed) so that overfull boxes may be avoided.
In this example there is no glue to stretch, however if you use a pdftex based plain TeX you can use the HZ algorithm to slightly adjust character widths as an alternative to adjusting white space.
If you allow the characters to be squeezed enough then the word fits on the line with no hyphenation


\pdffontexpand\tenrm 35 35 5 autoexpand
\pdfadjustspacing=2

\parindent=0pt
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=40pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=41.52788pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\raggedright

\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=40pt E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip
\vbox{\hsize=41.52788pt E\-le\-fan\-ten } 
\bye


TeX uses a “penalty” system to choose its linebreaks.  An overfull hbox adds some penalty points, but if the alternative adds more penalty points, then TeX will still choose the overfull hbox.
In your example, a hyphenation-break would leave just Elephan- on the first line; this would either leave an underfull line, or require adding space between the letters.  Both of these are very strongly penalised in standard justified text — they’re essentially completely disallowed.
The following example adapts yours to add an extra word.  The inter-word space automatically includes some “stretchable glue”, which can stretch a little with minimal penalty, but not unlimitedly.  The first group forces the hyphenation break, so shows how much stretching the break requires; the second group shows how TeX happily accepts a little stretch, but if the required stretch would be too much, then TeX prefers the overfull line.

\parindent=0pt
\vskip\baselineskip % manual hyphenation
\vbox{\hsize=48pt die Elefan-\break ten }  
\vbox{\hsize=52pt die Elefan-\break ten }  
\vbox{\hsize=56pt die Elefan-\break ten }  
\vskip\baselineskip % TeX’s automatic hyphenation 
\vbox{\hsize=48pt die E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vbox{\hsize=52pt die E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\vbox{\hsize=56pt die E\-le\-fan\-ten }  
\bye

